# Testing Android Room with Kotlin Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm trying to test a `Room` DAO exposing functions that return `Flows`. The following test won't pass and I'm struggling to see why :

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `observeHomeCoursesFeatured() does not return courses that are no longer featured`() = runBlocking {
        val outputList: MutableList<List<HomeCourse>> = mutableListOf()
        launch { subject.observeHomeCoursesFeatured().collect { outputList.add(it) } }

        subject.saveHomeCoursesFeatured(listOf(getHomeCourseFeatured1(), getHomeCourseFeatured2()))
        subject.saveHomeCoursesFeatured(listOf(getHomeCourseFeatured1()))

        assertEquals(2, outputList.size)
        assertEquals(listOf(getHomeCourseFeatured1(), getHomeCourseFeatured2()), outputList[0])
        assertEquals(listOf(getHomeCourseFeatured1()), outputList[1])
    }
```

It fails at `assertEquals(2, outputList.size)` saying that `outputList` is empty.

This test passes :

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `observeHomeCoursesFeatured() does not return courses that are no longer featured`() = runBlocking {
        subject.saveHomeCoursesFeatured(listOf(getHomeCourseFeatured1(), getHomeCourseFeatured2()))
        assertEquals(listOf(getHomeCourseFeatured1(), getHomeCourseFeatured2()), subject.observeHomeCoursesFeatured().first())

        subject.saveHomeCoursesFeatured(listOf(getHomeCourseFeatured1()))
        assertEquals(listOf(getHomeCourseFeatured1()), subject.observeHomeCoursesFeatured().first())
    }
```

The second test passing, shows that my DAO is working fine and it is more a question of threading and concurrency between the test thread and the thread that `Room` uses to trigger `Flow` changes.

I already added `@get:Rule val archRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()` in my test. I also build my test DB with this :

```kotlin
db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(ctx, CoreDatabase::class.java)
            .setTransactionExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`launch` is asynchronous, so you have a race condition.

```
@Test
fun `observeHomeCoursesFeatured() does not return courses that are no longer featured`() = runBlocking {
    val job = async { subject.observeHomeCoursesFeatured().take(2).toList() }

    subject.saveHomeCoursesFeatured(listOf(getHomeCourseFeatured1(), getHomeCourseFeatured2()))
    subject.saveHomeCoursesFeatured(listOf(getHomeCourseFeatured1()))

    val outputList = job.await()

    assertEquals(2, outputList.size)
    assertEquals(listOf(getHomeCourseFeatured1(), getHomeCourseFeatured2()), outputList[0])
    assertEquals(listOf(getHomeCourseFeatured1()), outputList[1])
}
```

Comment: Now my test won't finish because ``runBlocking { subject.observeHomeCoursesFeatured().collect { outputList.add(it) } }`` runs endlessly. And that's normal, that's why I think I have to launch a coroutine using ``launch``

Comment: It's the same thing. My test won't end because ``join()`` waits for the coroutine to finish which it won't by itself because I'm calling ``collect()`` on a never ending ``Flow`` generated by Room.

Comment: Didn't realise it was a never ending `Flow`. Another update.

Comment: Instead of `runBlocking`,  `kotlinx.coroutines.test.runTest` could be used here. Followed by passing and using the `testDispatcher` & `backgroundScope` to collect on the DAO's flow.

Answer (score 1):

For this case I recommend to use flow.first()

```
@Dao 
interface TreeDao{ 

     @Query(Select * from tree) 
     fun getTrees():Flow<List<Tree>>}
}
```

For example Repository

```
class Repository(context:Context){
  db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, TreeDatabase::class.java)
            .build()

fun getTrees():Flow<List<Tree>>
}
```

Because of any flow is endless than for our testing we can take first value of flow.

```
@Test
fun GetList()=runTest{
  val list=repository.getDao().getTrees().first()
  Assert.assertEqual(1,list.size)
}
```